# Google Analytics tag with wrong GTM ID

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have an application with GTM head snippet. And GTM is set up with Universal Analytics tags for GA.

Everything was working great for months
2/22 - Data from GTM was not being sent to GA and I noticed a new console error

`analytics.js:3 GET https://www.google-analytics.com/gtm/js?id=GTM-NZ9RDTS&t=gtm1&cid=116215814.1516126796 net::ERR_ABORTED`

The GTM ID is not my GTM ID and I am not sure where its coming from.. any thoughts?

Comment: Ok that ID was coming from google optimize tag

Comment: Did you tried Google Tag Assistant to cross check? Empty tag can also trigger an error

Answer (score 1):

I am new to GTM, but I found another reason why there could be an unknown tag registered in GA. According to this discussion [post](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Analytics-Referral-Spam/Another-Google-tracking-code-is-showing-up-as-my-sites-tracking/td-p/582009#) on the community, it is possible that sometimes, a referral link could trigger GA to register foreign GTMs on your GA.

Comment: I was using Google Optimizer to experiment with and it leaves a GTM identifier. My experiment was in the draft but it still generates a GTM URL in the header.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience - new Google Optimize container with draft experiment. The Optimize container has been configured to be served through GTM and GTM container has been published. Whenever tried to check the integration an error appeared. Through Chrome Inspect I saw 404 for [www.google-analytics.com/gtm/js?id=](http://www.google-analytics.com/gtm/js?id=)

The solution was to publish the experiment. Then immediately unpublished (ended) the experiment as it was not properly configured. The errors related to Optimize container have disappeared.